# Difference between gl_Translatef and gl_Translatedf

Tags: opengl

Whats the difference between `gl_Translatef` and `gl_Translatedf` in openGl, 
I know `translatef` manipulates the matrix according to the parameters that you pass to it ....
But what does  `gl_Translatedf` do in comparison to former ?

Comment: You mean `glTranslatef` and `glTranslated`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a short hand notation for specifying which function signature options you have like `d=double`, `f=float`. There are `glTranslatef` or `glTranslated` so for short hand its sometimes written as `glTranslatedf`

[See here for examples here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872065(v=vs.85).aspx).